# Update ListView from Fragment A on a TwoPane activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the normal behavior of `TwoPane`

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the inverse?

Something like: a click from **Fragment B** would change the `ListView` items on **Fragment A**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Usually you have the parent activity listen for clicks and notify the other fragment. Just do it in reverse. So onClick from FragmentB, tell the parent:

```
 void onClick() {
    MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
    activity.onFragmentBClicked();
  }
```

Then have the parent update fragment A's list:

```
 void onFragmentBClicked() {
    fragmentA.updateList();
  }
```

Thats a very simplified example, so you will need to modify it to meet your needs. If you have A -> B working, then B -> A is the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I was a little bit confused about that. Here's an example if someone needs to call a method from FragmentA at Activity: `((ParameterListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.parameter_list)).setActivatedPosition(5);`

Answer (score 0):

Or use [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to achieve the same. Its publish subscribe nicely ***decouples*** your code.

From your fragment raise the event like following.

#### In your activity

```
@Subscribe public void doSomething(SomeEvent event){

}
```

#### In your fragment do this

```
YourApplication.getEventBus().post(new SomeEvent(x,y,z));
```